How to aggregate sum values "up to specific column"?
Imagine you have a budget spreadsheet, one column per month:





1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12




Salary
Joe
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000


Salary
Mary
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000


Office Enhancements
Printer





1000









What is the best way to have an aggregate sum "up to month X".
E.g.

Provided Month 3, we should see "Salary 12000" and "Office Enhancements 0"
Provided Month 6, we should see "Salary 24000" and "Office Enhancements 1000"

Here is a playground sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IO4UHF2CIXnKIu5m8DBcHfP9Il6sW59hAGWJ0waj9KE/edit?usp=sharing

SUMIFS, or SUM with a mixed reference, might be options.


If Cell_P1 has the month number listed(as in screenshot):
=query(hstack(A2:A,byrow(choosecols(C2:N,sequence(P1)),lambda(Σ,sum(Σ)))),"select Col1,sum(Col2) Where Col1<>'' group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc label sum(Col2) ''")


